# keras TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' ,when I use a self-defined merge function

Tags: merge, keras

```
cifar8 =  Input(name='cifar8',shape=(8,8,3),dtype='float32')
inner = Flatten()(cifar8)
en = Dense(1,activation='relu')(inner)
patch = Input(shape=(8,8,9),dtype='float32')
m = merge([en, patch], mode= scaleMult, output_shape = (None,8,8,9))
inner = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',activation='relu')(m2)
```

The function scaleMult means that the one element tensor 'en' multiply the 8×8×9 tensor 'patch'.
Of course, I should construct multiplication between 32*1 tensor 'en' and 32×8×8×9 tensor 'patch' when training in 32 size batch.

But there always shows the error 'fan_in = shape[1] * receptive_field_size TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'' at the Convolution2D step.